# jQuery variable is undefined if used or logged

Tags: jquery

I am trying to figure out why my variable is "undefined" but I can't..

```
var o_main_w = $(".sys_main_content").attr("style");
console.log(o_main_w);
```

The html looks like this:

```
<div class="sys_main_content" style="width:1140px"></div>
```

I basically need only the value "1140" not the whole thing.

I must admit that this might be because I am a newb lol
Can anyone point me in the right direction please? Thank you..

Comment: Just added the code..

Comment: It works fine... Make sure you are loading Jquery first... working fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/2DUrm/

Comment: It works for me in jsfiddle using all of the jquery versions, which leads me to believe there must be something else going on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `css()` jQuery function:

```
$(".sys_main_content").css("width"); // returns the width
```

or directly

```
$(".sys_main_content").width(); // returns same value
```

From documentation:

---

### `.css()` [¶](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

> Get the value of a style property for the first element in the set of
>   matched elements or set one or more CSS properties for every matched
>   element.

### `.width()` [¶](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

> Get the current computed width for the first element in the set of matched elements or set the width of every matched element.

Comment: Or `$(".sys_main_content").width()`

Comment: I am not lazy, believe me, just noob, I searched, but i thought this was the right way to do it..

Comment: I was updating the answer while @kingdamian42 put the comment. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @AdrianM. I was not calling you lazy, it's just an expression.

Comment: @iambriansreed Thanks, updated! I always prefer using `.css('prop')` instead of `.prop` for same unknown reason why I use `.attr('data-attr')` instead of `.data('attr')`. :-)

Comment: @AdrianM. You are welcome. We learn new things every day! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use this instead:

```
var o_main_w = $(".sys_main_content").css("width"); // Returns string "1140px"
o_main_w = parseInt(o_main_w); // Returns "1140" as an integer
```

Answer (score 1):

surely because `$(".sys_main_content").attr("style");` does not exist!

is jQuery loaded ? is your code in a `$(document).ready` section () ?

Comment: Then why alert ($(".sys_main_content").attr("style")); returns "width:1140px;"?

Comment: didn't see your html code when i'v posted the first sentence ... you added it after that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to parse out the issue...

```
console.log('.sys_main_content exists' + ($(".sys_main_content").length > 0));

console.log('.sys_main_content style' + $(".sys_main_content").attr('style'));
```